# Отправка формы после изменения данных на Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Есть форма:

```
<form ref="form" method="POST">
  <input type="text" :value="name">
</form>
<a href="#" @click.prevent="submit('Вася')">Инициирует отправку формы</a>

Компонент js:
{
  data{
    name: '',
  },
  methods:{
    submit(name){
      this.name = name;
      // форма отправляется до того, как изменится value инпута
      this.$refs.form.submit();
    }
  }
}
```

Проблема в том, что форма отправится до того, как изменится value поля этой формы, в итоге сервер не получает нужных данных. Работает, если в вместо this.$refs.form.submit() написать setTimeout(()=>this.$refs.form.submit(), 0) . Но как будет правильнее в этом случае. И почему вообще так происходит? Код с формой и компонентом просто для примера, в реальном приложении все сложнее, интересует именно этот момент с отправкой.

Answer (score 0):

> Работает, если в вместо this.$refs.form.submit() написать
>   setTimeout(()=>this.$refs.form.submit(), 0) . Но как будет правильнее
>   в этом случае.

Правильно использовать nextTick в таких случаях

> И почему вообще так происходит?

поэтому - https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: Может быть  использовать v-model и submit засунуть в тело form?